# problem to push volume beyond 100% on Ubuntu GNOME

Tags: gnome, sound, bash, pulseaudio

I made a bash script to push the volume beyond 100% in Ubuntu GNOME, to be able to start it during the boot process as my laptop's sound in Ubuntu is so weak.

The script is `/usr/bin/volume150.sh` and contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
pactl set-sink-volume 0 150%
```

First problem: the script doesn't run when double clicked.

Second problem: If I assign a keyboard shortcut with the command to rise the sound to %150 it goes to mute instead.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: After all the edits, it's now an excellent question!  +1  **;-)**

Comment: Which GNOME version?

Comment: @A.B. It is gnome 3.14, Ubuntu gnome 15.04 default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal and as an admin user type:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/volume150.sh
```

When you double-click it, it will ask you to execute or display.  Click execute, but that's not the default behavior. Open the <kbd>Settings</kbd> for Nautilus aka Files and make your choice for <kbd>Executable Text Files</kbd>

[image]

When you assign a keyboard short-cut to `/usr/bin/volume150.sh` it'll have the same effect as double-clicking it.

Comment: It's not giving me the option to execute.

Comment: I'm running plain vanilla Ubuntu with Unity so can't test that bit, but I'll ask our 2 resident Gnome experts to have a look at that.  But in the mean time: you've got a working script and a keyboard short-cut!

Comment: I'm a GNOME expert? :)

Comment: But I have no idea for the 150% --> mute thing. It works in my case.

Comment: @A.B. it worked for me to this time, thank you.

Comment: @Fabby thank you so much it did work, now i can double click to execute.

Comment: @RonnieNissan: A.B. did the last of the heavy lifting...  **;-)**

Comment: @A.B. then thank you, and thank fabby for telling you.